# How to get mail response from mandrill in laravel 5.7?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, mandrill

I am sending email with mandrill mail driver in laravel 5.7. I want to set webhook in mandrill for undelivered emails. For that i have to store "_id" in database from mail respons but i am getting null in response.

I have set 'mandrill' mail driver in config/mail.php and

```
'mandrill' => [
        'secret' => env('MANDRILL_KEY'),
    ],
```

in config/services.php

I have tried one solution from this link but no luck :( 
https://laravel.io/forum/05-25-2015-get-message-id-when-sending-email-via-mandrill-driver?page=1

Example code I am using to send email :

```
$response = Mail::to($toEmail)->send(new NewMailTemplate($data));
```

It should return following response :

```
[
    {
        "email": "recipient.email@example.com",
        "status": "sent",
        "reject_reason": "hard-bounce",
        "_id": "abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123"
    }
]
```

What change should I do to get correct response?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mail is coming in the email you are sending or not ?

Comment: Yes,email is successfully sending on to email.

Comment: \Mail::send('welcome', [], function ($message){
    $message->to('recipient_email_address')->subject(' Testing mail');
});
Can you try sending like this and check its working??

Comment: also can you check logs on mandrill??

Comment: Looking through the code for the `MailgunTransport` class it looks like it no longer returns the response.

Comment: @joy I have tried but not getting any response.

$response = Mail::send('emails.testmail',[], function($message)
        {
            $message->to('toemail')->subject('test');
        });
        dd($response->getBody()->getContents());
It gives error :
Call to a member function getBody() on null